# Error when starting hbase shell

Tags: macos, shell, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I have installed `hbase` with command : `brew install hbase` in my Mac-OSX-Yosemite-10.10.2. I am getting following error:

```
warning: -J-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 argument ignored (launched in same VM?)
warning: -J-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m argument ignored (launched in same VM?)
warning: -J-Xmx4096m argument ignored (launched in same VM?)
TypeError: can't convert Pathname into String
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1071
  require at file:/usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.1/libexec/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.8.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36
   (root) at /usr/local/Cellar/hbase/1.0.1/libexec/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:105
```

Result of `hbase  version`:

```
util.VersionInfo: HBase 1.0.1
```

Result of `java  -version`:

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

I had also download 'hbase-1.0.1.1-bin.tar.gz', and was running `bin/hbase shell`, but it was also giving me same error. Let me know how to resolve this?